# Iterating through a Java Map within a range

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I have a `TreeMap<LocalDate, TreeSet<EmployeeObject>` which contains `Date` as key and a `Set` of all employee whose birth date it is. I want to iterate this `Map` between two dates e.g `22/02/15 to 27/02/15`.  Is it possible to do it efficiently without having to traverse the whole `Map`?

(EDIT)Additional Question: As an alternate do you think a `Trie` or some other data structure is a better fit for this situation than a `Map` in storing birth dates for all employees and then later querying them between a range?

Comment: Try [TreeMap#navigableKeySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#navigableKeySet%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what sort of map you use. If you use a HashMap, no. If you use a TreeMap, yes (see [the NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface which it implements). If you use a Guava RangeMap, especially yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use TreeMap as the implementation  (or import data to it). It will give you access to NavigableSet for keys, or subMap view of the Map within the requested range (which you can iterate normally). They are views so the data are not duplicated.